# Can I use AWS Certificate Manager with Heroku SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, heroku, https, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) with [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) to enable SSL for my Heroku app?

If so, how?

If not, how can I get a free SSL/TLS certificate? Should I just use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can with a small hack.
Follow the steps:

> 1. Create a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager and approve it
> 2. Create a Cloudfront distribution with the `Origin Domain Name` as your heroku URL such as myapp.herokuapp.com and the custom SSL
>      certificate as the one you created from the AWS Cert Manager
> 3. While creating the distribution, make sure that you have the TTL as 0, else all the responses will be cached
> 4. Assuming that you have the DNS managed by Route53 (if it's not - you have to), point the domain name to the Cloudfront Distribution by
>      creating an A record

The drawback is that if you get too many hits on the website, your cloudfront billing might go up and one day you might consider paying $20/month to Heroku for the same!

Comment: Exactly how much is "too many hits"? Pricing for US and Europe is $0.085/Gb for the first 10TB. After that, you get bulk pricing. Free tier gives you 50GB and 2M requests.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the AWS Certificate Manager with Heroku. It looks like [Heroku has their own free SSL service](https://blog.heroku.com/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours).

**Edit:** As mentioned in another answer you can place CloudFront in front of your Heroku application and use a fre AWS ACM certificate with that. However, that solution comes with added expense and probably isn't what you are looking for.

Instead of using CloudFront I would recommend CloudFlare which provides a completely free solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about monthly pricing for using cloudfront as a workaround, however upgrading your heroku app dynos to the hobby plan for $7 a month comes with the added benefit of free ssl, I have this setup in production and it works great. More info can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management)