# How to configure a Amazon Route with SSL for a Heroku App

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, heroku, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I need to set an Amazon Domain as a custom domain for a Heroku app. I found the next tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53 but it doesn't work if the app needs https requests. The first idea was to set up the SSL Certificate in Heroku, but the SSL Amazon Domain manager doesn't allow to download the certificate, so the SSL need to be managed by AWS. 
What is the best way to add Amazon SSL to a Heroku app?

Comment: "but it doesn't work if the app needs https requests" why doesn't it? What specifically about using Route53 prevents you from using Heroku SSL exactly? I would focus on that issue instead of going down the path of AWS SSL certificates, which will not work with your Heroku app.

Comment: You are right, I haven't described the problem well. The request was allowed but as insecure because I haven't set the SSL. Then I tried the option of creating a CloudFront but a bad configuration causes an HTTP Methods Error. Finally, I solve it following some answers and guides and describe the process in this question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option I found was to create an AWS CloudFront and configure it like Karan describes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018918/4055731) but with some add-ons:

1. Create a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager and approve it.
2. Create a CloudFront distribution with the Origin Domain Name as your Heroku URL such as myapp.herokuapp.com and the custom SSL certificate as the one you created from the AWS Cert Manager.
3. While creating the distribution, make sure that you have the TTL as 0, else all the responses will be cached
   [image]
   [image]
   If you don't complete this step probably you will get an error like this:

   > This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for the request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
   >   [image]
4. Follow the guide I mention in the question `[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53][4]`

Comment: It should also be mentioned that cookies should be passed (depends on your app) since many apps use them.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon created SSL certificates only work with supported Amazon services such as Elastic Load Balancers, CloudFront distributions and API Gateway.

The easiest method to use Amazon SSL certificates is to add a load balancer. Another method is to enable CloudFront.

[AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)

Comment: I choose the CloudFront option and it works following a couple of guides. Thanks :)